# Firebase Realtime Child listener throws SocketTimeoutException while uploading to Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebase-storage

I have some sort of comments section in my app where I have attached a child event listener to get real-time comment update.

```
private fun addListener() {
    reference.addChildEventListener(this)
}


override fun onChildAdded(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
    val newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment::class.java)
    adapter.addToTop(newPost)
    key.add(dataSnapshot.key!!)
    errorDiscussion.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

While adding a new comment, tt works perfectly when I don't upload an image to FirebaseStorage and post a comment with null value to the `attachImage` field.

But when I try to upload an image to FirebaseStorage and add than try to push a new comment with `attachImage` field in that particular `databaseReference` the data actually get pushed to the database but the `onChildAdded` method is not invoked. And the listener is de-attached.

What I see in the logs are some `SocketTimeoutException`

```
08-30 09:18:43.175 12208-25905/np.com.aawaz.csitentrance D/NativeCrypto: jniThrowException: java/net/SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
08-30 09:18:43.693 12208-25905/np.com.aawaz.csitentrance D/UploadTask: Increasing chunk size to 524288
08-30 09:18:43.719 12208-25905/np.com.aawaz.csitentrance D/NativeCrypto: jniThrowException: java/net/SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Isn't it the good way to accomplish this task.

**Image Upload Logic**

```
    val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("discussion").child(fileName)

    val file = Uri.fromFile(File(image?.path))
    val uploadTask = ref.putFile(file)

    val progressDialog = MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
            .content("Uploading....")
            .progress(false, 100)
            .autoDismiss(false)
            .build()

    progressDialog.show()

    uploadTask.addOnProgressListener {
        val data = it.bytesTransferred / it.totalByteCount * 100;
        val progress = data.toInt()
        progressDialog.setProgress(progress)
    }

    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener {
        addCommentWithImage(addCommentTextDiscussion.text.toString(), fileName)
        progressDialog.dismiss()
        image = null
        itemSelected.visibility = View.GONE
    }


    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener {
        progressDialog.dismiss()
        it.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to upload image, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

**Database Push Logic**

```
    val comment = Comment(currentUser!!.uid, currentUser.displayName, System.currentTimeMillis(), message, currentUser.photoUrl!!.toString(), imagePath)
    val postValues = comment.toMap()

    reference.push().setValue(postValues)
```

Comment: Uploading to Cloud Storage through the Firebase SDK, and writing data to the Firebase Realtime Database are two completely separate communication mechanisms. The two have *nothing* to do with each other, so I doubt this is a problem that originates on the communications layer. What is the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: What is the error that you get?